# MinGW g++ gives warnings in the wrong language (German instead of English)

Tags: compiler-errors, environment-variables, g++, locale, non-english

My problem is the following:
When I compile a C++ Project with eclipse (Juno, 64bit, Java 7u3) on my Windows 7 laptop, I get german errors/warnings. This results in warnings showing as errors in eclipse.

###### Windows 7, 64bit, settings :

*Display Language:* English
*Format:* German (Switzerland)
*Location:* Switzerland
*Language for non-Unicode programs:* English (Canada)

On my other Windows 7 (64bit) computer, I have the exact same settings and don't have any problems.

I tried:

- Adding -Duser.language=en to the end of my eclipse.ini file.
  Which did not work.
- Changing the *Format* to English.
  Which actually worked but is not
  really an option due to the wrong format in other places.
- Many different things I can't remember
  (e.g. Environment variables in eclipse, etc.)
  Again, nothing helped.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I finally solved it :D
I just added a new environment varibale. I still have no clue why it works on one computer (as  on that one I have not set this variable) but at least it finally works on my laptop as well and is (I think) a good (the correct?) solution:

*Control Panel* -> *System* -> *Advanced System Settings* -> *Environment Varibales...* -> *System variables* -> *New..* -> Variable: **LC_ALL**, Value: **en_US.UTF-8**

Now I have english warnings/errors when I compile and eclipse behaves as it should.

Comment: +1, you have no idea how much time I've spend googling this. Thank you.