# Eclipse CDT with MinGW displays warnings as errors

Tags: eclipse, mingw, warnings, eclipse-cdt

I have a little problem.

I just installed Eclipse CDT and created a C project using MinGW and all my simple warnings (like "unused variable" etc) are shown as errors.

The program build fine and I can run it, but all these errors are annoying.

I already checked the compiler settings and "Warnings as errors (-Werror)" is unchecked.

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `-Werror` would be checked, the build would fail. By the way you should definitely check it so that it enforces you to take care of all the warnings right from the beginning.

You can suppress some warnings (but not all), with special options to GCC (MinGW). You can see which options are needed to suppress this or that warning in the end of the warning itself.

Nevertheless, I strongly recommend against it. It's rather better to resolve all the warnings right from the beginning. Strive to design your projects in the way that they are able to be built with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` options. There are 3 main benefits of this approach:

- Your code would be nearly bulletproof;
- Your code would conform to the standard closely;
- Your code would be more portable across different compilers
  (as some of them tend to treat some warnings as errors by default).

Remember, leaving the annoying warning flood is a bad habit, and you should definitely get rid of it right from the start.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question but I will take that, I always care of all warnings. But just in some cases I test my program without using a variable (when I comment a block of code or something), and it wouldn't build with -Werror, which is annoying. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: It answers your question precisely, in particular how to turn off warnings.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear, but my question was not to turn of warnings, but why eclipse or MinGW displayed warnings as errors.

Comment: If it would display warnings as errors, then your code would never compile. However, you've claimed _"program build fine and I can run it"_. So you definitely weren't clear.

Comment: Actually in the eclipse's Problem window, its says `3 errors, 0 warnings`, and says stuff like `variable set but not used` or `unused variable` whith a red circle next to it. These should be warnings, shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, they should be. If they appear as errors, then it can only mean that somehow `-Werror` is still passed to the compiler. Double check the command line which Eclipse uses to invoke GCC during the build. And once again, does your code compile despite there are these 3 errors?

Comment: I checked that, it's `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -c -fmessage-length=0`. I don't see `-Werror`.

Comment: As a final check go to `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis`: what `Severity` is there for `Unused variable declaration in file scope`?

Comment: Well, Bryan, either you're still missing something to tell me or your Eclipse is indeed magic! `;)`

Comment: I think it's because of me, but I don't know what, I left the default config and everything.. Thank you anyway, and by now I'm used to these errors, it isn't a big deal since I correct them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was caused because the compiler/builder's message was in a different language than Eclipse.

Thus, Eclipse could not identify them as `Warnings` and thought they were `Errors` instead.

I solved by making an environment variable to set the compiler to the right language, 

[Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191063/mingw-g-gives-warnings-in-wrong-language-german-instead-of-english)

As the messages were sent on the right language, Eclipse changed the markers to warnings and compiled without any error messages.